# Kafka Streams Application Connection to Bootstrap Server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have developed an application using kafka streams in kafka. Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Properties;

public class pega {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "pega-app");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "********:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        properties.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1000);

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();


        KStream<String, String> s_order_stream = builder.stream("first-test",  Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()))
                .filter((key,value) -> {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    return json.getString("op_type").equals("U");
                })
                .mapValues(value -> {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject("after").toString());
                    return json2.toString();
                });

        //KTable<String, String> table_test = builder.stream("WordCount-app-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000012-changelog",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()))
        s_order_stream.to("second-test", Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), properties);
        streams.start();

        System.out.println(streams.toString());

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
```

When I run the application in a local VM using `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG: localhost:9092`.
it runs properly. I created a fat-jar of this application, and when I try to execute it on a kafka cluster in a big data platform, using the IP **"gr412####:9092"** of one of the three brokers, the application is running but nothing happens to **"second-test"** node. It's like it doesn't connect. Am I using wrong configuration?

PS: From the node that I am executing the jar, I connect to every broker and zookeeper. It is not a connection issue.

Comment: can you check if the app is consuming `first-test` topic? like the lag of topic is decreasing, ? try add a mapValues before filter then print log to check if stream is consuming message or not?

Comment: Also I would recommend monitor the app by expose jmx to prometheus or something so you can monitor things like lags, consuming rate, is would be easier to detect problems

Comment: I would like to add that the topic from the stream is not created in topics. There is no changelog for the stream.

Comment: sorry, I did not get ` is not created in topics`?